# JDBC not working once program compiled

Tags: java, jdbc

I have just completed my first Java Program, it works inside netbeans...but when I clean and build and run the executable jar file, it opens the GUI but none of the database functions work. I tried using JSmooth but I was either doing something wrong or it was not working on my computer. Im assuming that when i run the program outside of netbeans it cannot find the JDBC jar? how can i fix this?

Comment: what is the error? how do you package your program to run (e.g. how do you gather all JARs required, how are you setting up your classpath etc)?

Comment: Post the error first so we can help you.

Comment: Have you got a "real" database? because Netbeans will create a derbyDB for you which wont be available if the IDE doesnt start it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most probably you are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` in the background. If you are starting your application from command line, you can specify jars to be on the classpath as follows:

```
java -cp jdbcdriver.jar my.package.MainClass
```

Comment: You should post this as comment if he is getting that exception.

Comment: He told that he is already assuming that, so if he does assume that then this is not a comment, but an answer.

Comment: This was my best for such a poor question. But SO is more about helping newcomers rather than just downvoting them, so at least maybe it helped.

Comment: ~Yes . I really hate people who just downvote the question without leaving comment.

Comment: I've only been programming in java for a little over a month now so Im aware there's a lot to learn. I am using a real sqlite database that I created outside of net beans. I will try jabals suggestion. Thank you